# Approximating the energy levels of the anharmonic oscillator using WKB

Tags: homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, approximations, semiclassical, anharmonic-oscillators

I got stuck trying to solve this problem:
Given the potential $$V(x) = \frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}-\beta x^4,\ \beta>0$$ I need to evaluate the deviation of the energy levels from the harmonic oscillator using WKB.
I tried to use Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization rule but that gives the following integral:
$$2\sqrt{2m}\int_{x_-}^{x_+}\sqrt{E-V(x)}dx~=~(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\hbar,$$
which I am not sure how to handle.

I tried thinking of subtracting the potentials in the integral but the boundaries of integration would differ between the cases.
I wonder is there another way of finding this deviation using WKB explicitly or am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the WKB expansion for the wave-function in the problem...

Comment: Wouldn't i still get the integral above for the zeroth order expansion?

Comment: My impression is you don't have to equate to the quantization rule, you should compute the deviations from it, without more context it is hard to tell, but I believe you should consider the $\beta$ term as a perturbation, namely compute the expectation value of that term in the old traditional harmonic oscillators states.

Comment: There is some confusion here between WKB, which is a rather general technique and the Bohr-Sommerfel quantization rule, which is the integral in the question, also derived using WKB.

Comment: @ohneVal unfortunately, i am not allowed to assume that $\beta$ is small and so the perturbative approach is not what they look for

Comment: @Vadim the question itself stated to use WKB, but in the relevant lecture we also solved several potentials using Bohr-Sommerfeld, hence, my approach to this problem.

Comment: @LLM has it worked with the approach outlined in my answer? I didn't have time to follow through all the details with the elliptic integrals.

Comment: @Vadim I am getting stuck in the integral again, it might be because i can't find the proper way of substituting the variables

Comment: @LLM could you checked the coefficient in front of $\beta$? The way it is written now the problem is poorly defined, since the potential goes to $-\infty$ at $x\rightarrow\infty$ (I haven't noticed it before.)

Comment: @Vadim yes i know, that is the actual question though

Comment: @LLM Then it is really about calculating wkb tunneling probability, since there are no stable states.

Comment: @Vadim how can i estimate the energy levels from that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest consulting the books on special fucntions: Abramovitz&Stegun and Gradshtein&Ryzhik - the indefinite integral is expressed in terms of the elliptic functions, but the definite integral is likely given by a simple expression, since the limits of integration are special points.

More specifically, GR3.155 (4,5,6) deals with integrals of the type:
$$\int dx \sqrt{(a^2 + x^2)(b^2 - x^2)}.$$

Our integral of interest is
$$\int_{x_-}^{x_+}\sqrt{E - \frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2} - \beta x^4}.$$
Expression under the square root is a square polynomial in respect to $y=x^2$, with roots $y_1 = b^2$, $y_2 = -a^2$, so that the turning points are given by $x_\pm = \pm b$, and the integral reduces to
$$\int_{-b}^{+b} dx \sqrt{\beta(a^2 + x^2)(b^2 - x^2)} =
2\int_{0}^{+b} dx \sqrt{\beta(a^2 + x^2)(b^2 - x^2)}.$$
Now one has to struggle through the elliptic integrals and variable substitutions of Gradshtein&Ryzhik, but the result should be rather simple.

Answer (score 0):

The integral with the anharmonic term doesn't have a closed form solution. If it did the anharmonic oscillator would have an exact solution. The best you can do is to do a perturbative expansion in terms of small values of the $\beta$ parameter which would give you a the first few terms of an asymptotic series.